# CMake hunter error: `Unexpected MSVC_VERSION`

Tags: cmake, cmake-hunter

First of all, thank you for taking your time to help!

- System: Windows 10 x64
- cmake version: 3.24.1
- Visual Studio 2022 v17.3.3
- Console with admin privileges: Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022
- Perl (Strawberry Perl): perl 5, version 32, subversion 1 (v5.32.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

I am trying to compile kawpowminer from https://github.com/RavenCommunity/kawpowminer.

I already found some other solutions to similar errors but they haven't helped me.

Looked into those files (every single one printed out in the error) and found the lines with "hunter_add_package" as the cause of those errors.

I also changed 2019 to 2022 and 15 to 17 in those config files and edited the paths if needed.

I cloned at `C:\Users\MEuser\kp` the described git-project from "https://github.com/RavenCommunity/kawpowminer".
This is my script, the last line is causing the error. No errors are printed out before.

```
 mkdir kp
 cd kp
 git clone https://github.com/RavenCommunity/kawpowminer
 cd kawpowminer
 git submodule update --init --recursive
 cd build
 cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A X64 -H. -Bbuild -DETHASHCL=ON -DETHASHCUDA=ON -DAPICORE=ON ..
 cd build
 cmake --build . --config Release
```

---

Console: Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022

```
 CMake Warning:   Ignoring extra path from command line:
 
    "C:/Users/Meuser/k2/kawpowminer/build"
 
 
 -- [cable ] Cable 0.2.14 initialized
 -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
 -- [cable ] Configurations: Release;RelWithDebInfo
 -- [hunter] Calculating Toolchain-SHA1
 -- [hunter] Calculating Config-SHA1
 -- [hunter] HUNTER_ROOT: C:/.hunter
 -- [hunter] [ Hunter-ID: e14bc15 | Toolchain-ID: b0b5bc7 | Config-ID: 196746b ]
 
 [hunter ** INTERNAL **] Unexpected MSVC_VERSION: '1933' [hunter **
 INTERNAL **] [Directory:C:/Users/MEuser/k2/kawpowminer]
 
 --lol------------------------- ERROR ------------------------lol--
     https://docs.hunter.sh/en/latest/reference/errors/error.internal.html
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 
 CMake Error at
 C:/.hunter/_Base/Download/Hunter/0.23.214/e14bc15/Unpacked/cmake/modules/hunter_error_page.cmake:12
 (message): Call Stack (most recent call first):  
 C:/.hunter/_Base/Download/Hunter/0.23.214/e14bc15/Unpacked/cmake/modules/hunter_internal_error.cmake:13 (hunter_error_page)  
 C:/.hunter/_Base/Download/Hunter/0.23.214/e14bc15/Unpacked/cmake/modules/hunter_setup_msvc.cmake:73
 (hunter_internal_error)  
 C:/.hunter/_Base/Download/Hunter/0.23.214/e14bc15/Unpacked/cmake/modules/hunter_finalize.cmake:117
 (hunter_setup_msvc)  
 C:/.hunter/_Base/Download/Hunter/0.23.214/e14bc15/Unpacked/cmake/modules/hunter_add_package.cmake:23
 (hunter_finalize)   CMakeLists.txt:56 (hunter_add_package)


 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

---

I did found similar errors in the internet and on stack but nothing really helped me.
I also searched through the files and the config (CMakeLists.txt) and researched some lines, but I really didnt found anything interesting, similar or working.

(it's 5am in my country, please don't assume I didn't researched a lot or anything, I am just lost)

I also tried different includes for the HunterGate like
include("cmake/HunterGate.make")

```
HunterGate(
    URL "https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/archive/v0.23.33.tar.gz"
    SHA1 "abcf4b9b77b5a0160abc1da1cdda35f64b14196a"
)
```

But at this point I have to admit, I don't know what I am actually doing...

Answer (score 1):

Investigating your error message,

```
 [hunter ** INTERNAL **] Unexpected MSVC_VERSION: '1933' [hunter **
 INTERNAL **] [Directory:C:/Users/MEuser/k2/kawpowminer]
```

I'm pretty sure this is fixed by [this hunter PR ("Add support for Visual Studio 17 2022" `#484`)](https://github.com/cpp-pm/hunter/pull/484), which added the following to `:/cmake/modules/hunter_setup_msvc.cmake`:

```
  # ...
  string(REGEX MATCH "^193[0-9]$" _vs_17_2022 "${MSVC_VERSION}")
  # ...
  elseif(_vs_17_2022)
    set(HUNTER_MSVC_VERSION "17")
    set(HUNTER_MSVC_YEAR "2022")
  # ...
```

The solution is to update your hunter version to get this fix.

I think the [Hunter first step docs](https://hunter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start/boost-components.html#first-step) should be all the information you need. Just change the HunterGate URL to use `v0.23.317`.

---

You get a gold star from me for providing so many details in your question (I think you were just missing what hunter version you're using).

If I could add a bit more to my answer, I'd say that reading long error messages to find the important parts and googling key phrases is useful (a skill? / a helpful trick?). If this is truly the cause of your issue, with luck, it's possible to find the answer yourself in less than 5 minutes. I just read your error message, and googled:

```
hunter "Unexpected MSVC_VERSION"
```

(the quotes means to look for an exact match)

, which led me to [hunter_setup_msvc.cmake in the old hunter repo](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/blob/master/cmake/modules/hunter_setup_msvc.cmake), and then I just went to the new repo, went to the file, and (by luck) the GitHub banner for most recent commit said "`tnixeu add msvc17_2022 to huter_setup_msvc.cmake (#484)`".

* Bonus link to [wikipedia on MSVC versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering).